# How can i enable specific pathes to work with http

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a spring boot application with the following settings:

```
# The format used for the keystore
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/localhost.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=passwort
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost
#only accepting ssl requests
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

Now i have a couple of Restendpoints.
I just want one specific Endpoint like "receiveFile("/receiveFile")" to only allow ssl secured connection like "https://". all the other should accept normal http request like "http://l...."

How can i get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Spring Security configuration.
The main idea: we are able to configure endpoints permission separately.

- HTTPS is for "*/receiveFile*" endpoint
- HTTP is for all other endpoint

Solution might look like this:

```
@Configuration
    public class SslWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.defaultSuccessUrl("/app/dashboard")
                  .and().requiresChannel().antMatchers("/receiveFile").requiresSecure();
 
        }
    
    }
```

More details: [Baeldung: 5. Mixing HTTP and HTTPS](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-channel-security-https#mixing)

Comment: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated